# Creating a directory tree

Tags: java, path, tree, directory, traversal

For a program I'm trying to create a directory tree. So the first part of my program uses Paths to traverse the directory I need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path startingDir = Paths.get("/home/somedirectory");
    PrintFiles pf = new PrintFiles();
    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, pf);

}
```

And the PrintFiles program (I directly copied this from the guide on how to use paths for walking a tree) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html:

```
public static class PrintFiles extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    //Print information about each type of file.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attr) {
        if (attr.isSymbolicLink()) {
            System.out.format("Symbolic link: %s ", file);
        } else if (attr.isRegularFile()) {
            System.out.format("Regular file: %s ", file);
        } else {
            System.out.format("Other: %s ", file);
        }
        System.out.println("(" + attr.size() + "bytes)");
        return CONTINUE;
    }

 //Print each directory visited.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
        System.out.format("Directory: %s%n", dir);
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        System.err.println(exc);
        return CONTINUE;
    }
```

}

I also have a generic tree program that creates a tree with any number of nodes, with the typical add nodes remove nodes etc functions (I'm not going to post the code because its long and I don't think its really necessary since its a pretty standard implementation).

My question is how exactly do I do something where I can create a generic tree that represents the directory tree for my specific directory? I'm not exactly familiar with how the Path and File libraries work.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I would consider using apache commons io fileutils to walk the dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement `preVisitDirectory, postVisitDirectory and visitFile`.  And you'll need  to hold the "current node" in your visit implementation.

- In pre create a new node, add it to `currentNode` and then set `currentNode = newNode`
- In visitFile create a new leaf node and add it to `currentNode`
- In post set `currentNode = currentNode.getParent()`

So sort of like a stack operation where you "push" in `preVisit` and "pop" in `postVisit`.

Comment: I understand how this algorithm works, but how exactly do I control when to call each of these functions? Like for example the whole traversing is done inside the walkFileTree function, so do I need to make my own implementation of this?

Comment: You just need to implement the FileVistor interface and pass that implementation to the walkFileTree function.  It does that walk and calls your visitor class at appropriate points.